# How to clear ID Field on any Sharepoint List

Tags: list, custom-list

How could I Clear Id field after testing a List, and start with ID 1. Because Ech Test Increase my ID Field of 1. After All Test I would Like to start with ID = 1 on production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot clear the ID field out of the box in SharePoint

Instead the list can be taken as template and then delete and recreate it with the saved template

Comment: But sometimes it destroy Workflow.

Comment: Yes... ID field cannot be reset. You can try having a new column and use that for ID